Google analytics hit returning 302 for purchase events

Purchase event of checkout success page is returning 302 error. We have recently enabled enhanced conversion to collect user data. I am not sure if that have cause this problem.
Below is my datalayer code.
dataLayer.push({
    event: "purchaseGA4",
    ecommerce: {
        transaction_id: "2158369",
        value: 19.97,
        tax: 3.73,
        shipping: 0.0000,
        currency: "EUR",
        affiliation: "TEST",
        coupon: "",
        enhanced_conversion_data: {
            email: "test@test.com",
            phone_number: "+91234567890",
            address: {
                first_name: "test",
                last_name: "test",
                country: "test"
            }
        },
        items: [{
            'item_name': "test",
            'item_id': "7141",
            'price': 19.97,
            'item_brand': 'test',
            'item_category': 'test',
            'item_category2': 'test',
            'item_category3': 'test',
            'item_variant': '',
            'quantity': "1",
            'index': "0"

        }, ]
    }
});


302 is not an error, it's a redirect. Explore the 302 response, find the location. If the location is there, then see where it redirects. If it's not there, then it's a 302:Found. Which kinda acts as 200 sometimes. In any case, go check your data and see if you see the 302 purchases with proper payloads.
